# Trying to use FindView with a path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewengine

I'm trying to check if a couple of views exist by using paths. But the views cannot be found even if they do exist.

```
private string SelectFirstView(ControllerContext ctx, params string[] viewNames)
{
    return viewNames.First(view => ViewExists(ctx, view));
}

private bool ViewExists(ControllerContext ctx, string name)
{
    var result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ctx, name, null);
    return result.View != null;
}
```

And how I try to find the views:

```
var viewName = SelectFirstView(ctx, statusCodeName,
                               "~/Error/" + statusCodeName,
                               "~/Error/General",
                               "~/Shared/Error",
                               "Error");
```

Note that `"~/Shared/Error"` and `"Error"` is the same view, but only the latter is found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are working with paths you need to specify the extension as well:

```
~/Error/General.cshtml
~/Shared/Error.cshtml
...
```

When you don't specify a path you don't need the extension as in this case the view engine follows standard conventions to discover the views.